# Wpf app not start up with windows when cinstall like uwp package

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, uwp, startup

I wanna start up my wpf app with windows. But it isnt work when i install it like an uwp app.

This is the code which set start up in run time:

```
static public void SetStartup()
        {
            DeleteStartup();
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            rk.SetValue(Global.GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + @"\" + Global.GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME);
        }

        static public void DeleteStartup()
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            key.DeleteValue(Global.GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME, false);
        }

        static public void SetStartLocation()
        {
            RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            if (RegKey.GetValue(GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME) != null)
            {
                string Path = RegKey.GetValue(GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME).ToString();
                Path = Path.Remove(Path.Length - GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME.Length, GlobalConstant.APPLICATIONNAME.Length); // Now it's a valid directory.
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path);
            }
    }
```

But it isnt work because uwp app install itself in the specific folder.
(C:\Program Files\WindowsApps)

Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to install a WPF application as an "UWP app", you should use the [desktop bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root). I am not sure what you are trying to do with the registry.

Comment: This uwp only avaible on pc so i wanna start up my app with windows.

Answer (score 0):

> This uwp only avaible on pc so i wanna start up my app with windows.

@mm8's suggestion was correct. For the regular UWP apps, Startup is supported from the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 1709).

If your application is a classic WPF application, you need to use [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to package your WPF application, then you could declare startup task extension in the `Package.appxmanifest`. After that, when you generate a package for your desktop app, you could install it as an UWP app. It will startup when the system startup.

Please see [StartupTask Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask) for more details.

> Please note: Desktop Bridge apps can set their startup tasks to Enabled in the manifest, in which case they do not need to call RequestEnableAsync. However, the user must launch the Desktop Bridge app at least once before it will launch at startup or user login in.

Comment: How can i use startupTask in wpf app?

Comment: @GAMINGBEX You might not understand what I said. You first need to package your wpf app by 'Desktop Bridge'. For example, you could [Package your WPF application by using Visual Studio (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net). Then, you could see a `Package.appxmanifest` file in this project. After that, you follow the [StartupTask Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask) document to add startup task extension declaration in this `Package.appxmanifest`.

Comment: It is okey for you and i did it. But not clear for me that how can i set start up in run time?

Comment: @GAMINGBEX You do not need to set startup at run time. When you declare startup task extension in the Package.appxmanifest, you install it on your machine and launch it at least once. Then, it will startup at next time when system startup.

Comment: I wanna that user can set it.

Comment: No. The user only can change the enabled state of your app at any time via the Startup tab in Task Manager. They can not set it in app.